# Ruby access instance variables from another method

Tags: ruby

I have a class and I try to access an instance variable and I noticed I can do it in both ways by addressing it with `@` and without it. Why si there no error when I call it without a `@` `puts "name : #{name}"`?

```
class Blabla
    attr_accessor :name

    def initialize(blabla)
        @name = blabla
    end

    def populate()
        puts "name : #{name}"
        puts "name : #{@name}"
    end

end
```

Comment: 1. Those are not "class instance variables", just regular instance variables. Terminology is important. 2. because of `attr_accessor :name`

Comment: with `attr_reader :name` I have the same, so is there any way I can avoid this behavior but still be able to read the instance variable?

Comment: yeah, why do you put `attr_accessor` / `attr_reader` there, again?

Answer (score 3):

As hinted in the comments:

```
attr_accessor :name
```

is shorthand for:

```
def name
  @name
end

def name=(name)
  @name = name
end
```

So expanding your code we have:

```
class Blabla    
  def name
    @name
  end

  def name=(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def initialize(blabla)
    @name = blabla
  end

  def populate()
    puts "name : #{name}"
    puts "name : #{@name}"
  end
end
```

`#{name}` references the method `name` which returns `@name`.

`#{@name}` references `@name` directly.

Also be sure to understand `attr_reader`, `attr_writer` methods.